# AWS DataPipeline EvaluateExpression using Java SDK

Tags: java, aws-sdk, amazon-data-pipeline

Using the [AWS DataPipeline API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html), I'm trying to programmatically evaluate an [Expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-pipeline-expressions.html) like the following:

```
sometext-#{format(@scheduledStartTime, 'YYYYMMddHHmmss')
```

To evaluate the expression, I'm using a `PipelineObject` that looks something like the following:

```
Id:@MyPipelineObject_2018-08-26T01:00:00
Name:@MyPipelineObject_2018-08-26T01:00:00
     - Key:@scheduledStartTime
     - StringValue:2018-08-26T01:00:00
     - Key:@scheduledEndTime
     - StringValue:2018-08-27T01:00:00
```

How can I evaluate the expression, given that I know the pipelineId and pipelineObjectId? I'm using the [Java AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/datapipeline/model/package-summary.html), and creating an `EvaluateExpressionRequest` like so:

```
String expressionToBeEvaluated = "sometext-#{format(@scheduledStartTime, 'YYYYMMddHHmmss')";
String myPipelineObjectId = "@MyPipelineObject_2018-08-26T01:00:00";

EvaluateExpressionRequest evaluateExpressionRequest = new EvaluateExpressionRequest()
                .withPipelineId(myPipelineId)
                .withExpression(expressionToBeEvaluated)
                .withObjectId(myPipelineObjectId);
```

However, from the docs it's not clear to me how to actually issue the request with the `EvaluateExpressionRequest` object. I've looked at [`EvaluateExpressionResult`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/datapipeline/model/EvaluateExpressionResult.html) but the `setEvaluatedExpression` method only takes a `String` as input.

Am I doing something wrong, missing something fundamental, or does the SDK just not support what I'm trying to do?

Any input or suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out a few minutes after posting my question. It turns out the answer is very simple and I've just been looking at this stuff for too long. The `DataPipeline` object has the method [`evaluateExpression()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/datapipeline/DataPipelineClient.html#evaluateExpression-com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.model.EvaluateExpressionRequest-) which takes an `EvaluateExpressionRequest` and returns the `EvaluateExpressionResult`. You get the evaluated result by calling `getEvaluatedExpression` on the returned object.

```
EvaluateExpressionRequest evaluateExpressionRequest = new EvaluateExpressionRequest()
                .withPipelineId(myPipelineId)
                .withExpression(expressionToBeEvaluated)
                .withObjectId(myPipelineObjectId);

dataPipeline.evaluateExpression(evaluateExpressionRequest).getEvaluatedExpression(); //evaluates to sometext-20180826010000
```

Hope that helps anyone with a similar affliction!